# Why does GNU Scientific Library not allow matrices with more columns than rows for singular value decomposition?

Tags: c, matlab, linear-algebra, gsl

MATLAB allows a matrix with more columns than rows when computing the singular value decomposition.

```
>> a_matrix = [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0;
     0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0;
     0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0;
     0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

a_matrix =

     1     0     0     0     2
     0     0     3     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     2     0     0     0

>> [u, s, v] = svd(a_matrix)

u =

     0    -1     0     0
    -1     0     0     0
     0     0     0    -1
     0     0    -1     0


s =

    3.0000         0         0         0         0
         0    2.2361         0         0         0
         0         0    2.0000         0         0
         0         0         0         0         0


v =

         0   -0.4472         0         0   -0.8944
         0         0   -1.0000         0         0
   -1.0000         0         0         0         0
         0         0         0    1.0000         0
         0   -0.8944         0         0    0.4472
```

But the GNU Scientific Library (GSL) does not.  It gives this error:

```
gsl: svd.c:61: ERROR: svd of MxN matrix, M<N, is not implemented
Default GSL error handler invoked.
```

Is this a shortcoming of the GSL or can it be worked around?

Comment: Can't you transpose the input and then transpose `s` and swap `u` and `v`?

Comment: The answer is probably that the developers were lazy...

Comment: Regarding my previous comment: you should apply _complex-conjugate transpose_ (not just transpose), in case you are dealing with complex input

Comment: A working solution is suggested above, regarding the rest of your question and @MarcoBonelli 's comment I do have a few words. There is literally only one person who develops and maintains the library despite having a full-time job, if you still think he is lazy and/or the package needs more development even after that, you can always submit a patch or report a bug/feature request.

Comment: @LuisMendo you should add more text/code to your comment and post it as a separate answer since this is a working solution.

Comment: @Bracula Thanks. I'd rather wait for Paul to confirm if it works for him. I don't use GSL so I couldn't test it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int run_svd(const gsl_matrix * a) {
  // Need to transpose the input
  gsl_matrix *a_transpose = gsl_matrix_alloc(a->size2, a->size1);
  gsl_matrix_transpose_memcpy(a_transpose, a);
  printf("a_matrix'\n");
  pretty_print(a_transpose);

  int m = a->size1;
  gsl_matrix * V = gsl_matrix_alloc(m, m);
  gsl_vector * S = gsl_vector_alloc(m);
  gsl_vector * work = gsl_vector_alloc(m);

  gsl_linalg_SV_decomp(a_transpose, V, S, work);
  printf("U\n");
  pretty_print(V); printf("\n");
  printf("V\n");
  pretty_print(a_transpose); printf("\n");
  printf("S\n");
  gsl_vector_fprintf(stdout, S, "%g");

  gsl_matrix_free(V);
  gsl_vector_free(S);
  gsl_vector_free(work);

  return 0;
}
```